# Prometheus - undefined receiver \"null\" used in route

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Why am I getting receiver null used in route? Commenting out the route related to `null` still produces the same error.

Any idea how to resolve this? Does the config look correct? It did work yesterday but I deleted everything and tried to reinstall and I get this error.

`failed: provision alertmanager configuration: base config from Secret could not be parsed: undefined receiver \"null\" used in route`

Also how can I have separate email for each alert? When it works it usually sends a groped alert. Can I just disable route section and have only receivers? Would that send alerts separately? `group_by: ['...']` still sends by grouping..

```
  config:
    global:
      resolve_timeout: 5m
    route:
      group_by: ['job']
      group_wait: 30s
      group_interval: 5m
      repeat_interval: 30m
      receiver: 'null'
      routes:
      - match:
          alertname: Watchdog
        receiver: 'null'
    receivers:
    - name: 'null'
    route:
      group_by: ['...']
      receiver: 'email-alert'
    receivers:
    - name: 'email-alert'
      email_configs:
      - to: test@gmail.com
        from: test@gmail.com
        smarthost: postfix.test-internal:25
        require_tls: false
```

Here is the log entries:

```
level=info ts=2020-12-21T03:17:54.675369726Z caller=operator.go:1163 component=prometheusoperator msg="sync prometheus" key=monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
level=error ts=2020-12-21T03:17:54.678077463Z caller=klog.go:96 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="Sync \"monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager\" failed: provision alertmanager configuration: base config from Secret could not be parsed: undefined receiver \"null\" used in route"
level=info ts=2020-12-21T03:17:57.297131904Z caller=operator.go:661 component=alertmanageroperator msg="sync alertmanager" key=monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager
level=info ts=2020-12-21T03:17:57.29721675Z caller=operator.go:1163 component=prometheusoperator msg="sync prometheus" key=monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
level=error ts=2020-12-21T03:17:57.301610335Z caller=klog.go:96 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="Sync \"monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager\" failed: provision alertmanager configuration: base config from Secret could not be parsed: undefined receiver \"null\" used in route"
level=info ts=2020-12-21T03:17:59.906899712Z caller=operator.go:1163 component=prometheusoperator msg="sync prometheus" key=monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
level=info ts=2020-12-21T03:17:59.909936845Z caller=operator.go:661 component=alertmanageroperator msg="sync alertmanager" key=monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager
level=error ts=2020-12-21T03:17:59.915494013Z caller=klog.go:96 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="Sync \"monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager\" failed: provision alertmanager configuration: base config from Secret could not be parsed: undefined receiver \"null\" used in route"
```

Answer (score 5):

In YAML, `null` and `"null"` aren't the same thing.

- `null`: represents NULL value
- `"null"`: represents a string equal to `"null"`.

Try removing the qoutes:

```yaml
      routes:
      - match:
          alertname: Watchdog
        receiver: null
    receivers:
    - name: null
```

Comment: Btw, it is okay to have 2 routes?

Comment: @John No, you can't have two `routes` keys at the same level, and you can't also have two `receivers:` keys at the same level. But you can have multiple values for same key, as they are array types.

Comment: Can you share an example on how to set it up?

Comment: @John Take a  look: https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/blob/master/doc/examples/simple.yml

Comment: That worked. But the alerts are grouped into a single email. How can I get separate email for each alert? I mean can I just disable `route section` and just have `receivers`? I'll update the question